# Having Trouble Navigating Between UIViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

Let me start by saying that I want to do all of this without storyboards. My situation is as follows: I have a login page for the user. On the login page the user can login, or be taken to a register page. When the user registers successfully, they are taken to the main menu. However, if I they click logout from the main menu, dismissing the main menu viewcontroller takes me back to the register page (which makes sense).

The problem is I need to take the user to the login page. However, I cannot present the original login page because I get the error "Warning: Attempt to present  on  which is already presenting "

Is there some sort of way for me to dismiss 2 view controllers? Or maybe run a line of a code on a view controller if it is presented from a certain view controller?

Thank you!

**This is the solution that I used from the main menu and it worked**

```
 if(self.presentingViewController == registerPage){
            registerPage.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: One way you can do: put all viewControllers into a navigationViewController and then use navigationViewController.viewControllers and navigationViewController.popToViewController() to manage your stack :)

Comment: @Breek would I be able to pop two controllers? Because what I essentially need to do is backup 2, not just 1.

Comment: Yes, if you are able to access your loginViewController instance then you can do navigationViewController.popToViewController(loginViewController, animated: true). Otherwise, you can iterate in your navigationViewController.viewControllers to get your loginViewController

Comment: That makes tons of sense, I'll try it out today. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to switching to Navigation controllers.

If you are presenting view controller than simply try this:

**For Objective-C:**

```
[[[self presentingViewController] presentingViewController]  dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

**For Swift:**

```
self.presentingViewController!.presentingViewController!.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {})
```

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: That seems to be in objective-c. Do you know the swift equivalent?

Comment: @DMop just edited answer, you can see there for swift

Comment: That looks great! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a navigation controller, you can get the `viewControllers` array property, build up a new array without the viewControllers you want to dismiss and set the property with the new array.

Comment: All of the controllers I have now are ViewControllers. Would it make sense to switch to navigation controllers?

Comment: Navigation controllers are for a stack of screens that you want to navigate forward and back.  Once the user logs in, I would just reset the window.rootViewController to the mainVC.  When they logout, I would reset the root to loginVC.  Main or Login may sit within a NavVC if you need a stack within, but login and main should not be in the same NavVC, I think.

Comment: That makes plenty of sense. Does resetting the rootViewController serve to change the stack in of itself?

Comment: The root is a single VC not a stack. It could be a NavVC which holds a stack. Any VC could also be presenting a single other VC.